# How to determine inefficient query in teradata?

Tags: performance-testing, teradata

I am able to calculate these metrics for my teradata queries from dbc.DBQLOGTBL table. Metrics - SPOOLUSAGE, CPUIMPACT, IOIMPACT, CPUSKEW, TOTALCPUTIME, TOTALIOCOUNT, PJI, UII.

If I want to know which are the bad queries based on these metrics then which all important metrics should i look for and how I will calculate the optimum range of those metrics for my query.

Comment: This is one of those questions that is just too open ended for Stack overflow. All of this depends on what you care about.  A bad query might be one that runs in 20 seconds, but takes up dozens of gigabytes of Spool. Or it might be a query that only ever fills up a few megabytes of spool, but is crazy with I/O. There is no optimum since it's dependent on your system, load, requirements, etc... It's a lot of moving pieces and there is no silver bullet.

Comment: Teradata has recommendations around PJI and UII ratios to help identify suspect queries that are a Google search away. Otherwise, please refine your question as @JNevill suggested.